# Logging and tracing ActiveMQ Artemis JMS messages from a specific consumer

Tags: logging, trace, activemq-artemis

We have an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster and wish to trace the messages transferred back and forth from a specific/problematic consumer.

I know we can trace all JMS messages with the logger `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms` as stated in the official [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.25.0/logging.html).

But tracing **all** JMS messages is too much, and I wish we could filter the JMS logging to a specific queue or and/or a specific consumer.

We wish to identify the consumer with what ever is available to ActiveMQ [id,session,client id, address] or any other attribute.

From each messages we need the content (json), session, time of receipt (i.e. the time a message is accepted by the broker), time of delivery (i.e. the time a message leaves the broker).

Comment: How would the broker identify the specific/problematic consumer? What's unique about it that the broker could use to separate logging for it vs. all the other consumers? Also, what exactly do you want to log?

Comment: Following your comment, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "time of receipt" and "time of delivery"? Are you talking about the time the broker receives the message and the time it delivers the message to the consumer?

Comment: yes, the time a message is accepted by the broker, and the time a message leaves the broker.